# Building gstreamer 0.10 under Win32 via Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, gstreamer, glib

There is no more installer for GStreamer 0.10 available on GStreamer website (only versions 1.x). I really need to work with this version so I tried to build it from source. I found this laconic page explaining how to do:

http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-integration-win32.html

GStreamer depends on GLib so I decided to download and run GTK installer (http://gtk-win.sourceforge.net/home/). Then I added GTK2-Runtime/bin to my PATH variable.

When I try to do ./configure in GStreamer directory (via Cygwin), I get:

```
checking for GLIB... configure:
configure: error: This package requires GLib >= 2.24 to compile.
```

Which is strange because the GLib version installed is 2.28.8. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to complicate life, you can download/install Gstreamer as part of the [Cygport project](https://sourceware.org/cygwinports/) .